# Pass data to stored proc and return data to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm writing a asp .net webpage to pass textbox data to a stored proc and return a gridview of data on a button click. I've started writing the code but I'm getting confused as to how I allow the items to control the actions on the page. I.e. have the button click pass the field values to a stored proc to get data back.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>MSS Archived Data</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <!CDATA[
// ]]>
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="First Name: "></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Last Name: "></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Street: "></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="City: "></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="State: "></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Zip: "></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                    </td>                    
                </tr>
            </table>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                DataKeyNames="actID" DataSourceID="PersEWD_Database">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actID" HeaderText="actID" ReadOnly="True" InsertVisible="False"
                        SortExpression="actID"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actLogCreateDate" HeaderText="actLogCreateDate" SortExpression="actLogCreateDate">
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actCustomerID" HeaderText="actCustomerID" SortExpression="actCustomerID">
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actCampaignID" HeaderText="actCampaignID" SortExpression="actCampaignID">
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actActionDate" HeaderText="actActionDate" SortExpression="actActionDate">
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actActionCode" HeaderText="actActionCode" SortExpression="actActionCode">
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actRelevantInfo" HeaderText="actRelevantInfo" SortExpression="actRelevantInfo">
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actUnderwriter" HeaderText="actUnderwriter" SortExpression="actUnderwriter">
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actAmount" HeaderText="actAmount" SortExpression="actAmount">
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actPolicyType" HeaderText="actPolicyType" SortExpression="actPolicyType">
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actPolicyNumber" HeaderText="actPolicyNumber" SortExpression="actPolicyNumber">
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actReasonCode" HeaderText="actReasonCode" SortExpression="actReasonCode">
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="actSSN" HeaderText="actSSN" SortExpression="actSSN"></asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    //Here we declare the parameter which we have to use in our application
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlParameter sp1 = new SqlParameter();
    SqlParameter sp2 = new SqlParameter();
    SqlParameter sp3 = new SqlParameter();
    SqlParameter sp4 = new SqlParameter();
    SqlParameter sp5 = new SqlParameter();
    SqlParameter sp6 = new SqlParameter();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string myConnection = "dsn=dsnNAME";
        string serverName = "serverName";
        string dbName = "dbName";
        string storedProcName = "";
        string parameterName = "@RecordType";
        int parameterValue = 0;
        string myConnString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="+serverName+";Trusted_connection=yes;DATABASE="+dbName+";";




        OdbcConnection myConnection = new OdbcConnection(myConnString);
        myConnection.Open();
        //myConnection.Connection = myConnection;
        myConnection.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myConnection.CommandText = "{call " + storedProcName + " (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@lName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@street", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@state", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@zip", SqlDbType.varchar).Value = TextBox6.Text;

        myConnection.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Connection.Close();
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is rather vague, can you be more specific as to the part you are having problems with? And perhaps post the code you have so far. SO is a question/answer site, not a "write my code for me" site :)

Comment: Sorry about that. I have included the code above. Basically what I'm after is passing what the user enters in some fields to a stored proc/ sql query and return the data to a grid.  I can't figure out how to pass the data.

Answer (score 1):

The lifecycle of your data binding looks a little something like this:

1. Button Click - Your button will trigger a Click event when the user presses it. From here you'll want to call your stored procedure, using the value in the TextBox.
2. Data Retrieval - You execute your stored procedure using the parameter specified, and get a collection of data elements back. Depending on what version of the .Net Framework you have available, I'd recommend either using [TableAdapters](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/15/Building-a-DAL-using-Strongly-Typed-TableAdapters-and-DataTables-in-VS-2005-and-ASP.NET-2.0.aspx) (older technology, gives you a table structure that mirrors your database) or use [LINQ/Entity Framework](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) (newer technology, give you an object based off of your table and provides a list of those objects based off of the query). LINQ/EF is some amazing stuff, but some dev environments still aren't up to .Net 3.5 yet.
3. Data Binding - After you get the data back from your stored procedure, you'll set that as the DataSource of your GridView and then call the DataBind method. The GridView control will automatically handle iterating through the data you give it. If you need to do some custom columns/formatting, you'll override the [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event.

There are a lot of nuances and details to each aspect of this process, but hopefully this gives you the basic understanding of things in which to start with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you provide an example to help drive the point home. I roughly understood what I was after, lifecyclewise and you've proved out the concept. I'm can't quite seem to figure out how to code it.

Comment: I've figure out the passing of the arguments. It was simpler than I was making it.

Comment: It's kind of hard to provide a complete example in an answer here without it getting too long, but take a peek at the links above, they provide code samples and you should be able to piece it all together from them.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You need to set your select command to the name of the stored proc, then set the SelectCommandType to StoredProcedure. Then set the PropertyName of your ControlParameter.

This will set up your GridView to be databound to the value of the text box on postback (button click can cause a postback)

Also set your GridView's DataSourceID to match the ID of your SqlDataSource.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Database" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString %>"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_ConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
            SelectCommand="dbo.yourstoredproc" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
            OnSelecting="Database_Selecting">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Text1" Name="CustomerID" PropertyName="Text" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated my code. I went at it from a different direction. I decided to create the connection using C# for more control. Now I'm having trouble creating an ODBC connection, any thoughts?

Comment: Post a new question with the code and error you can't figure out. And choose an answer for this question if you can

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers:

1) Use `<asp:textbox id="Text1" runat="server"/>` rather than `<input name="CustomerID" id="Text1" type="text" />` - note the runat="server" this allows the datasource selectparameters to find its input source.

2) Point your gridview datasourceid to your sqldatasource if that's indeed where the data is coming from. Otherwise, where is "PersEWD_Database" data source defined?

3) Make your sqldatasource sql script return all the fields required to be bound on the grid not just the CustomerID.

4) Remove the empty `<script>` block unless you need it.

5) Remove `OnSelecting="Database_Selecting"` unless you need it.

6) Change `<asp:Button> onclick()` to `onclick="ButtonSearch_Click"` and implement the `ButtonSearch_Click` event handler in the code behind to repost the page. You could probably leave the event handler empty if you don't need to do anything other than load the grid with the typed in customer id.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I have updated my code. I'm now having trouble getting the sql connection to work. I really would like to create the connection with an odbc dsn. Which I have created on my machine. Having trouble getting the final pieces.

Comment: you could use this site http://www.connectionstrings.com/ to help you build the right connectionstring.